# Can someone tell me what this sign means?

Tags: notation

Here it is

∝

Have never seen before and google search hasn't given any results.

Comment: This represents proportionality. Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols

Comment: Oh, thanx a lot :) Cheers!

Comment: Oh, I always thought it was $\frac{3}{4}\cdot \infty$. =)

Answer (score 2):

The symbol is often used to show that something is proportional to an other quantity.

Please check if this is in the meaning of the symbol by checking the context.

For more information you should tell us more about the context: e.g. where is used the symbol, in which topic did you find the symbol.

Comment: Yes i checked the context again and it does match, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) could be useful to for such problems. In this case you would have learned that the symbol has the Latex command "\propto"

Answer (score 0):

Notice that visiting [the Wikipedia article on “∝”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%e2%88%9d) will tell you the answer:

[image: screen grab of relevant wikipedia article]

and the first section of this article explains the ∝ symbol.

Answer (score 0):

It is the proportionality symbol, which is read as "proportional to." The symbol tells us how the quantity on the L.H.S. is related to the R.H.S.

For example, "work ∝ time" means that if time increases, work also increases and vice-versa.

On the other hand, work ∝ $\frac{1}{sleep}$ means "if sleep increase work decreases and vice-versa."